# How to put SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Advanced and With Tools editions in the Visual Studio 2008 as ClickOnce prerequisites

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, clickonce, sql-server-express

Like i said in the topic: I would like to add SQL Server 2008 R2 Express editions as ClickOnce installation prerequisites for my application in Visual Studio 2008. I can create package.xml and product.xml similar to those from SQL Server 2008 Express bootstrapper that I took from vs2010, but I don't have the public key for SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe. Does anyone know how to find this public key???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the last question from the post: How to find the public key for a SQL Server Express package.

The public key is actually included in the SQL Server Express installer itself. To get to it start by right-clocking the package and selecting **Properties**. When the **Properties** window appears select the **Digital Signatures** tab. It should look like this:

[image: Digital Signatures tab of file Properties window]

Next select the only signature on the **Signature list** and click **Details** button. **Digital Signature Details** window will appear, looking like this:

[image: Digital Signature Details window]

On this window click **View Certificate** button. When the **Certificate** window appears select **Details** tab, like this:

[image: Certificate Details tab]

We're almost there! Just select **Public Key** property from the list and copy its value to the right attribute in the `package.xml` file and then remove spaces and line-breaks (when copied to the clipboard, the public key is formatted as it appears in the text box).

Comment: Hi would you please explain how to add SQL 2008 in VS2008 as prerequisites.
I have created a Setup&Deployment project.In solution explorer I selected RootNode of solution and Right ClicK and go for properties in   Properties menu i have selected prerequisites in prerequisites list there is only SQL Express 2005 and there is no item for SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a discussion with the product team lead for SQLExpress about them making bootstrapper packages available when service packs or new versions are released. I've sent him an e-mail asking for either a new bootstrapper package or the public key information you've requested. I expect to see this question a lot in the MSDN ClickOnce forum, so I'm hoping he'll help out. I'll report back. Just wanted to let you know someone was looking for an answer for you.

Comment: I got a response from the SQLServerExpress product team lead. He agrees they should provide this, and he's taken the prerequisite package for SSE2008SP-1 that is already included in VS2008 and modified it to work with R2. He says he has to test it and get it verified. I'm trying to get a time frame out of him, so I'll report back when I do...

Comment: It appears to me that SQLExpress 2008 R2 is in CTP. You're really going to deploy a CTP version to a customer?